# Email-to-case vs OWA

Tags: email, email2case, emailmessage, visibility, organization-wide

I've recently added new email addresses to email-to-case. These email addresses are now available to all the people in the org as 'from' addresses when they send an email to the customer. I tried to limit visibility of these email addresses to specific profiles by adding them to Organization-Wide Addresses but it didn't work in any way (I added the same emails in OWA but all profiles can still see addresses from email-to-case).

Is there any way not to show/limit visibility to these email-to-case email addresses? I would like only specific profiles or roles to be able to see them while they send an email from Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this discussion/ idea.  This is a well known issue https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdlvMUAR/restrict-which-address-you-can-send-an-email-from

Answer (score 0):

as of now this feature is not available to limit the visibility of the email address in the from Address field. But you can default a particular email address in the from address field, if you are using the email component  from a case Action. In that particular action , you can use the predefined field values and set the 'From' field to your desired email address. Of course this can be changed by user, so we are just defaulting one email address.

Hope this helps.